# Trasform ENV format string into JSON file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I've a `.env` formatted like this:

```
NODE_ENV=development

SERVER_PORT=5000

DB_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017
DB_NAME=test
DB_USER=user
DB_PASS=*****
```

I use [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) package (from NPM) to manage all app option, like server port and database connection

All `config` data are stored in JSON files like this:

```
{
  "server": {
    "port": 5000
  },
  "db": {
    "url": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "name": "test",
    "user": "user",
    "pass": "*****",
  }
}
```

Now I've to write down all the data into `config` file (JSON) from `ENV` every time NodeJS starts

How can I do?

Comment: try https://github.com/kerimdzhanov/dotenv-flow